# Is the phrase "transmembrane segment" equivalent to the transmembrane domain of a protein?

Tags: molecular-biology, cell-biology, proteins, cell-membrane

I am reading the [Handbook of Neurochemistry and Molecular Neurobiology](https://www.google.com.au/books/edition/Handbook_of_Neurochemistry_and_Molecular/0nCiPiyu3yEC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=Handbook%20of%20Neurochemistry%20and%20Molecular%20Neurobiology&printsec=frontcover)  and I am learning about the cell adhesion molecule NCAM2 and I have come across the following:

> The overall structure of NCAM2 is similar to that of NCAM. Thus, NCAM2
> consists of five Ig‐modules (supposedly of the C2‐type) followed by
> two Fn3‐modules. The protein exists in a GPI‐anchored isoform and in a
> transmembrane isoform that contains a 20–25 amino acid transmembrane
> segment followed by a 106–119‐amino acid cytoplasmic tail (Alenius and
> Bohm, 1997; Yoshihara et al., 1997).

I know that NCAM2 is located at the cell membrane and has an extracellular, transmembrane and intracellular domain. However, for the above statement: *The protein exists in a GPI‐anchored isoform and in a transmembrane isoform that contains a 20–25 amino acid transmembrane segment followed by a 106–119‐amino acid cytoplasmic tail*, is the term 'transmembrane segment' equivalent to the transmembrane domain? Further is the term 'cytoplasmic tail' equivalent to the intracellular domain? Any insights are appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

### Yes

I'll admit defeat in trying to find the section in the text you linked - if there's any one thing Google can't do, it's *search*.  But questions like this are better put to [Uniprot](https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/O15394), which gives quite a bit of information.  Following that link, you'll see they identify 21 AA of transmembrane *topology* from 698 to 718, with a cytoplasmic domain afterward.  So the cytoplasmic tail *is* the intracellular domain.

In a sense there is a second transmembrane domain - the [signal peptide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_peptide) from 1-19 - but because it is cleaved little attention is paid to it.  The extracellular domain starts at 20, with an N terminus *outside* the cell.

To quote Wikipedia, a [transmembrane domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmembrane_domain) "usually denotes a single alpha helix of a protein".  You should probably listen to them on such an issue because nobody is more fixated on semantics (it's a sort of vote).  Philosophically, you can picture that multiple transmembrane segments could operate as a functional unit - but each of these segments would be separated by some region of extracellular or intracellular sequence from the next.  A "domain" in a protein is a self-contained unit in the *primary sequence*, not just a series of helices that turn out to be near each other, so that wouldn't work.  And in fact if you look at a [GPCR paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC22163/) they speak in standard terms of seven transmembrane domains even while analyzing how they function together.